# Need to obtain shopping cart sum after series of getDocument price lookups

Tags: swift, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the total of a shopping cart in Firestore by executing a series of for loop calls that calculate the sum of items in the shopping cart.

The shopping cart is stored in a table called **carts** and the view upon appearing is pulled into an in-application dictionary called cartCache, of the type [String: Int]? where the key is the UID for the item and the value is the quantity of the item. However, the price of the item is stored in another collection called **items**. I only want to calculate the sum when the view appears or disappears, and then make it appear in a UILabel.

Thus, in order to obtain the sum and report it to a user (by modifying a label, or writing it to the cart), I need to iterate over each item in my cart and grab the price via an API call getDocument(completion:). However, this means that the calculation of the sum is asynchronous, which is not necessarily a problem, but I'm not sure of how to give a completion handler to a for loop. Is there an easier way to do this?

```
for item in self.cartCache!.keys
      {
        let doc = self.itemCollectionRef.document(item).getDocument
        {
          (itemDocument, error) in
          {
            guard let itemDocument = itemDocument, itemDocument.exists else {return}
            sum += itemDocument.data()!["price"] as! Int
          }
        }
      }

//Do something with sum (no guarantee at this point that sum is actually calculated, how do I add
//a completion handler to a for loop or obtain multiple field's values at once?
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to use is a `DispatchGroup`. `DispatchGroup`s allow you to run multiple asynchronous functions at once, and have one "completion handler" that is called once every asynchronous function completes. Some basic code looks something like this:

```swift
//Create your dispatch group. This is going to manage all of your asynchronous tasks and run some code when they complete
let group = DispatchGroup()

for x in array {
    //Call enter before the asynchronous function
    group.enter()
    asnynchronousFunction(completion: {
        //Call leave once the asynchronous function completes
        group.leave()
    })
}

group.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
    //Inside of group.notify, run whatever code you want to run upon completion of all asynchronous functions.
    //group.notify is your "completion handler"
})
```

So, for your instance, it would look something like this:

```swift
let group = DispatchGroup()
for item in self.cartCache!.keys
      {
        group.enter()
        let doc = self.itemCollectionRef.document(item).getDocument
        {
          (itemDocument, error) in
          {
            guard let itemDocument = itemDocument, itemDocument.exists else {return}
            sum += itemDocument.data()!["price"] as! Int
            group.leave()
          }
        }
      }

group.notify(queue: .main, execute: { 
    //All of your asynchronous functions have completed. You are ready to move on
})
```

**Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup**

**More in depth: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5371-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-2-2#toc-anchor-002**